# Bootstrap modal not working in jspx

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, modal-dialog, jspx

I am trying to use Bootstrap modal in jspx but it won't work. but it works in a HTML file. Do I need to add anything specific in jspx or does it not work in jspx?
Can anyone solve this problem please?

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"/>
<jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Home Page</title>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   <!-- Optional theme -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>

 <!-- main.css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Click me</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>modal title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

 <!-- Javascript files -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```